# Infinite integral of Bessel function (2nd kind) product Gaussian

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions, integration

I'm trying to evaluate the following infinite integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-\alpha x^2}Y_0(\beta x) \,dx$

If we apply the general result in [Gradshteyn & Ryzhik](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) (eq. 6.631.2 on page 706), with $\mu=1$ and $\nu=0$ then the result should be

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-\alpha x^2}Y_0(\beta x) \,dx=-\alpha^{-\frac{1}{2}}\beta^{-1} \sec\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha}\right)\left[-M_{\frac{1}{2},0}\left(\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right)+W_{\frac{1}{2},0}\left(\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right)\right]$

but $\sec\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is undefined (diverges).

However, Mathematica gives a finite result in terms of Meijer-G functions which I am not familiar with.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

With [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/) I have:

$$\int_0^{\infty } x \exp \left(-a x^2\right) Y_0(b x) \, dx=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a}} e^{-\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \text{Ei}\left(\frac{b^2}{4
   a}\right)}{2 \pi  \sqrt{a} b}
$$
where Ei is [exponential integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how you would calculate this without using Maple?